# Why won't the latest Xcode download the iOS 17.2 simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

Internet connectivity is fine. Sometimes it dies after a minute sometimes after five minutes, but after about twenty attempts, it always dies. Been installing Xcode on this machine in this location for years. Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: try commandline

Comment: I am having the same problem

Comment: have the same problem installing ios simulator. does not starts where it left off.

Comment: same problem with me. It automatically cancels after some times. i attempted it multiple times

Comment: Anyone found the solution ?

Comment: I encountered a close problem, it downloaded to 100% though but failed just after, 
in my case it was because my disk did not have enough memory left.
After clearing some spaces it worked well.

Comment: First, download the iOS Simulator 17.2  Runtime.dmg from your [Apple Developer Account](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/). The direct link is https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

You can then run the following command:

`xcrun simctl runtime add "Path to downloaded dmg file"`
e.g. 
`xcrun simctl runtime add "~/Downloads/iOS_17.2_Simulator_Runtime.dmg"`

Comment: @alvinchesaro appears in red color as a duplicate of a {long hex code} and is still not usable.

Comment: I was able to download and install iOS Simulator 17.2.dmg by using @alvinchesaro solution. 